# How to get searched Input in Material UI AutoComplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [material ui](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api) in reactjs.

```
<Autocomplete
              id="combo-box-demo"
              options={top100Films}
              
              getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                console.log(option)
                return option.title
              
              }
              }
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              onInputChange ={(event) => testMethod(event)}
            
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search here" variant="outlined" />}
            />
```

I have Following Issues:

1. How to get the searched input value
2. To show dropdown only after typing search text
3. Filter options based on search input

Comment: did you see examples https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban, yes, I didn't find these questions answer there.

Comment: I found but may be I didn't understund your questions right